# Crazy .net / Sharepoint error involving random temp files not found

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, sharepoint-2007, sgen

Logged into a customer environment today to check logs and just generally do an inspection, only to notice some tasks had failed in one application.

Application is written in c# .net v4 running inside of IIS and exports to Sharepoint 2007.

I can't be 100% sure if .net or SharePoint is the culprit. These are the errors I got:

> Task Failed: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> Could not find
>   file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\qbckfur1.dll'.
>   Export 26.05.2011 15:00:21 Failure
>   Task Failed: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> Could not find
>   file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\2shjg2xb.dll'.
>   Export 26.05.2011 15:30:13 Failure
>   Task Failed: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> Could not find
>   file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\b7utp199.dll'.
>   Export 26.05.2011 16:00:15 Failure
>   Task Failed: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> Could not find
>   file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\ozr2umkm.dll'.

Does this look familiar to anyone?

Comment: Restart SharePoint/AppPool. If that fails, restart IIS. If that fails, restart Windows. Problem solved \o/ (What process are those errors being logged for?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find file "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\xxxx.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318637/could-not-find-file-c-windows-temp-xxxx-dll)

Comment: I would recommend recategorizing the question as Serialization and not SharePoint, or adding keywords for the sake of the general population.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with `XmlSerialization` (beleive it or not).  I ran into this with a custom ASP.NET MVC app.  Apparently, when you call `Serialize` or `Deserialize` on types marked as "Serializable", .NET will generate an assembly on-the-fly to support the serialization and it attempts to write that assembly  into 'c:\windows\temp'.

Even if `Everyone` has full control access to that directory I have still seen this occur when running an app from within an IIS App Pool.  Especially in applications that has a lot of serialization activity.

If this sounds like your problem, the solution is to "pre-compile" the Serialization assembly and include it in your application with `sgen`, part of the Windows SDK.

This post highlights a similar issue: [Serialization issue on MSDN Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f5b4f7ff-ea13-4055-bc57-61855ad0daae/)

Here is the MSDN article on the tool: [sgen reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Final Note: There is a separate version of the Tool for .NET 4.0 so make sure you are using the correct version when generating your assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot this sounds exactly like my problem. Good to know for future reference.